# Suggestions for Outdoor Activities in Cambridge?

Tags: adventure, activities, outdoor-activities

Obviously my plans are delayed with the current situation - but I was meant to go and meet up with a friend who's going to be living in Cambridge later this year. I'm looking for some cool outdoor activities to do - while I'm going to be immersing myself in the town's history, he's gonna get bored of that very quickly, and need something a little more exciting to do. We were thinking of [going punting](https://www.puntcambridge.co.uk/), and looking to see if there were any paintball/go-kart or similar activities anywhere around.

Comment: A short web search (when everything is back to normal) will show you all activities you can do. This kind of question does not belong on this site.

Comment: It may be obvious to you where you are referring to, but Wikipedia lists approximately [50 places](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cambridge_(disambiguation)) called [Cambridge](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/2531_Cambridge).

Comment: @Arthur'sPass But there's a hyperlink in the post that narrows down the search.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a bit extreme, but you could try skydiving? Either way, thinks are going to be locked down for a couple weeks and most of these kinds of activities are closed now.

Comment: Worth a shot, thanks! I'm aware yes. Luckily the trip hasn't been booked yet or anything, so it'll happen when it happens.

Answer (score 1):

In the current situation no.
The British Government has ordered all non-essential businesses to close and has banned gatherings of more than 2 people unless for essential reasons.

So places like go-karting, paint balling etc. will be closed to slow the spread of the virus.
The full list of places to close is here [Guidence on Places to Close](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/874732/230320_-_Revised_guidance_note_-_finalVF.pdf)